# Finding the smallest number $n$ such that every two-colouring of the edges of $K_n$ contains a Path on 3 vertices

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

What is the smallest number $n$ such that every two-colouring of the edges of $K_n$ contains a (not necessarily induced) path on 3 vertices?

Comment: Sorry, Do you mean a path where every edges has the same color?

Comment: @mathnoob yes, all edges should have to have the same color

Comment: Seems like $K_3$ already does the job which makes me think that you meant to phrase the problem differently. (A path on $3$ *edges*, for example.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a path on 3 vertices , $K_3$ works as it is garanted that two of the three edges have the same color, well then they form a path on three vertices.   If what we want is a path of length $3$, my guess is $5$. Look at a vertex $u \in V(K_n)$, there are 4 edges connect to it. It is guarantee that at least two of the edges $e_1,e_2$ connected to it have the same color. So the edges connected to $e_1$ and $e_2$ not via $u$ must be color the other color. But then that gives a path of length 3 in the other color.

Also, here is an example of coloring of $K_4$ that does not admit a path of length 3, the edges are colored using numbers 1 and 3.
[image]

Comment: Am I right????????????

Comment: Seems right to me, modulo a coloring of $K_4$ that does not contain a path of length $3$ (which is not hard to find).

Comment: Great! Thank you!